# When using <p class=xxx> I am getting the response "No p element in scope but a p end tag seen." on W3C compliance checker

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I have just run my site (benefacto.org) through a W3C Compliance Checker. It bombed - it has multiple instances (50+) where it says

> No `p` element in scope but a `p` end tag seen.

I've counted (using MS Word) and I have exactly the same number of `<p class=xxx>` as I do `</p>`.

I think it is because I'm using `<p class=xxx>` or `<p class="xxx">` rather than `<p>`.

Can anyone help me get rid of this issue please?

```
<div class="row-constrained">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="p3 pink">Why is community involvement important to AECOM?</p>
        <p class="p1">As a global organisation we want to ensure that we support the communities where we live and work.</p> 
        <p class="p1">We have a skilled workforce who we support to make a positive impact on local community groups.</p>
        <p class="p1">Our aim is to make a positive difference for our people, our stakeholders, our communities and the environment.</p> 
        <p class="p3 pink">What do you think the key challenges are when engaging staff in the community?</p>
        <p class="p1">Finding organisations to work with is, surprisingly, a big challenge. We need a variety of activities which will appeal to the broad skills and interests of our people. Supporting smaller groups is also important for us.</p>
        <p class="p3 pink">How has Benefacto helped resolve these?</p>
        <p class="p1">By presenting an easy to use website, which allows people to find the right volunteering opportunity, manage themselves and take responsibility for their volunteering commitment.</p>
        <p class="p1">As Benefacto works with multiple corporate firms they bring lots of insight and ideas into what works and what doesn't work when getting employees engaged with volunteering. This has included provding a lot of practical support too - from presenting at team meetings to visiting volunteers and collecting case studies to producing marketing videos and printed materials.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="p3 pink">How did you launch the initiative?</p>
        <p class="p1">With a series of campaigns: including posters, intranet announcements, social media, television-screens in cafes, leaflets, etc. A launch event we ‘camped out’ in our cafe over the lunchtime period encouraging people to sign up to the mailing list.</p>
        <p class="p3 pink">How do you see your partnership with Benefacto progressing?</p>
        <p class="p1">We have signed up for the next year and hope to continue the momentum. We hope that in time, we can introduce Benefacto to other Regions.</p>
        <p class="p3 pink">Would you recommend Benefacto to other organisations?</p>
        <p class="p1">Definitely - and I have!</p>
        <p class="p3 pink">What advice would you give to someone just starting an employee volunteering scheme?</p>
        <ul>
            <li class="l1">Make sure you have a clear policy so people know what they can/can’t do</li>
            <li class="l1">Have a variety of options for people to choose from</li>
            <li class="l1">Make the process easy for them to manage themselves so it doesn’t become a logistical nightmare for you</li>
            <li class="l1">Share the stories post event to encourage involvement</li>
            <li class="l1 pink">Use Benefacto!</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is not in the code shown, that validates fine. On the page mentioned, you have multiple instances where a closing `</p>` tag occurs, without an opening `<p>` tag before it, or a closing `</div>` as part of a previously opened `p` elements content. If that code was written by hand, someone needs a crash course in HTML basics; if it was generated by a CMS, either that system needs fixing or the templates used to generated the output.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. 

Definitely isn't what is written by hand that is fine. I've been through and double checked that there are exactly the same number of </p> as there are <p> or <p class...>. 

It seems like the problem is occurring where it is being transferred from where I put it in in Wordpress to where it is published.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not necessarily about pure _numbers_ of opening and closing tags, but also about _nesting_ of elements. If you have for instance a `<div>` inside a `p` element, then that `p` element is _implicitly_ closed where the opening `<div>` tag occurs, because `p` can not contain a `div` element – and that would leave you with a closing `</p>` for which the validator does not see an opening `<p>` any more.

Comment: Hi CBroe, once again thanks for taking your time to reply.

Actually, i found out what the issue was - for some reason wordpress was adding </p> when there were indent spaces (like space bar spaces) in the code.

Komodo put these indents in automatically to help keep the code organised, but with them in it created the </p>. I did a find replace in Komodo and re-pasted the code in. Works like a dream.

However, code is now very messy looking as no indents :-(.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's saying you don't have opening p tags you should review all of those tags to find out where the extras are coming from.

You'll either need to reconcile your opening and closing tags or hire someone to go through and do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

On your current home page’s line 291 you have a closing `p` tag without a preceding opening one:

```html
</p></div>
```

Several more of these lines follow (when viewing the source code in Firefox, it’ll mark these superfluous closing `p` tags in red).

Comment: Unor, that is excellent advice - thank you. I've done that and can see the code exactly how you suggest.